# Tell Keystone.js to use no favicon

Tags: keystonejs

I fail to tell `Keystone.js` not to use any favicon.ico in my Keystone powered website.

I removed the json field 'favicon':'public/favicon.ico' (even though the [API reference](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/) doesn't say much about it)
Worth to notice that there's no favicon tag in the produced HTML and appearently anywhere else in the sources sent to the browser. Yet, I still have the **404 error** on /favicon.ico.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is KeystoneJS specific. Many browsers automatically look for `favicon.ico` in the root of websites, and if they find one it's used for bookmarks / tab icons / etc.

The `favicon` setting in Keystone is just there to customise the path to the file you want to serve as `/favicon.ico` in the root of your site, in case you don't want it to be served from `public/favicon.ico`.

Chrome, IE and Safari look for the file in the root of your website regardless of the presence of a `<link rel="icon" ... />` in the page `<head>`. This is probably the cause of the 404 error you're seeing.

For more information, see the [Favicon Page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) and the [Favicon Guide on W3C](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).

---

As a side note, the templates for the Admin UI do specifically include a favicon link tag, with the assumption that you will have one there. In this case it's not really different to the default behaviour of the major browsers, but if you think that should be customisable I'd suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues).